# Error dealing with $q.all and promises in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

Given the following code:

```
function Ctrl($scope, $http, $q) {
  var search = function(name) {
    if (name) {
      $http.get('http://api.discogs.com/database/search?type=artist&q='+ name +'&page=1&per_page=5').
        success(function(data3) {
          $scope.clicked = false;
          $scope.results = data3.results;
        });
    }
    $scope.reset = function () {
      $scope.sliding = false;
      $scope.name = undefined;
    };
  };
  $scope.$watch('name', search, true);

var done = $scope.getDetails = function (id) {
    $scope.clicked = true;
    $scope.sliding = true;
    var api = 'http://api.discogs.com/artists/';
    return $q.all([$http.get(api + id),
                  $http.get(api + id + '/releases?page=1&per_page=100')]);
};

done.then(function (){
 $scope.releases = data2.releases;
 $scope.artist = data;
 return $http.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=e8aefa857fc74255570c1ee62b01cdba&artist=' + name + '&album='+ title +'&format=json');
});
```

I'm getting the following console error:

```
TypeError: Object function (id) {
    $scope.clicked = true;
    $scope.sliding = true;
    var api = 'http://api.discogs.com/artists/';
    return $q.all([$http.get(api + id),
                  $http.get(api + id + '/releases?page=...<omitted>... } has no method 'then'
at new Ctrl (file:///C:/Users/Zuh/Desktop/AngularJS%20Discogs/js/services.js:27:9)
```

Can anybody point me to where might the error be? I'm defining the .then after getDetails is executed...

Here's a [working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fK5LDpxHj5NBwOlvNS3z?p=preview).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your updated plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/lTdnkRB1WfHqPusaJmg2?p=preview

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);

  function Ctrl($scope, $http, $q) {
    var search = function(name) {
      if (name) {
        $http.get('http://api.discogs.com/database/search?type=artist&q='+ name +'&page=1&per_page=5').
          success(function(data3) {
            console.log(arguments)
            $scope.clicked = false;
            $scope.results = data3.results;
          });
      }
      $scope.reset = function () {
        $scope.sliding = false;
        $scope.name = undefined;
      };
    };
    $scope.$watch('name', search, true);

    var done = $scope.getDetails = function (id) {
        $scope.clicked = true;
        $scope.sliding = true;
        var api = 'http://api.discogs.com/artists/';
        var q =  $q.all([$http.get(api + id),
                      $http.get(api + id + '/releases?page=1&per_page=100')])
                  .then(function (ret){
                     //console.log(arguments)

                     $scope.releases = ret[1].data.releases;
                     $scope.artist = ret[0];
                     return $http.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=e8aefa857fc74255570c1ee62b01cdba&artist=' + name + '&album='+ title +'&format=json');
                   })

        return q
      };

  }
```

To sum up fixes:

- move $q.all().then() part into done method
- pay more attention to what parameters handlers received in `then` part.

Comment: Now it gives me a ReferenceError: id is not defined. I've updated the Plunker. The ID it is supposed to come from the first $http of all, (not shown in the code above, but shown in Plunker). I'm new to Angular (and Javascript also) and sometimes is quite difficult to follow the info flow...

Comment: The id comes from a JSON response called with this:

$http.get('http://api.discogs.com/database/search?type=artist&q='+ name +'&page=1&per_page=5').
          success(function(data3) {
            $scope.clicked = false;
            $scope.results = data3.results;
          });

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49896/discussion-between-eric-mitjans-and-vittore)

Comment: Changed line 26/27 a bit, and it works [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fK5LDpxHj5NBwOlvNS3z?p=preview), all queries are done correctly, except the last one inside **then**, as it is not getting the "title" for each release in releases. The idea is to get the image url for each release in releases and pass it into the ng-repeat as an img, but I'll create a new question for this, you helped me more than enough! Thanks for the help and the patience!

Comment: @EricMitjans glad it worked for you. Try to either write tests for services iteraction or just debug/trace to control what you are receiving from ajax calls

Comment: @EricMitjans I noticed you have other questions about promises in angular. Check out egghead.io and start with this video https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-q-all